# if custom posts type exists and there are posts load script

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-enqueue-script, conditional-tags

I have registered a custom post type `'featured_post'`. I am looking for a way to test if the blog home page has any `'featured_post'` posts on it and if it has load a javascript file.

The 'featured_post' posts will make a slider at the top of the blog home page. I had this working using sticky posts but I can't work out how to conditionally load the script if there are posts of CPT 'featured_post'.

This is the code that worked for sticky posts:

```
 if ( is_front_page() && is_sticky() ) {
            wp_enqueue_script ('flexslider-js');
        }
```

However this does not seem to work and I don't know why:

```
    if ( is_front_page() && get_post_type('featured_post') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script ('flexslider-js');
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm at work at the moment (sorry boss), so I can't test this, but the snippet below should be the proper way of testing if the 'featured_post' post type exists, and then enqueue the script if it has any posts.

```
if ( is_front_page() && post_type_exists('featured_post') ) { // We are at the front page, and the post type 'featured_post' is registered.
    $hasposts = get_posts( 'post_type=featured_post' ); // lets check if there is any posts in the 'featured_post' post type.
    if( $hasposts ) { // If we found some posts, lets enqueue the script
        wp_enqueue_script ('flexslider-js');
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks very much! I am pretty new to php but that makes perfect sense now I see it.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has a helper function to do exactly this: [`post_type_exists()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_type_exists)

Example:

```
if ( post_type_exists( 'book' ) ) {
   echo 'the Book post type exists';
}
```